# How to find, whose ETH address it is?

Tags: transactions, ether

Is it possible to get personal information of a person using his ETH wallet address?

I did sell my ETH to one person, due to a technical glitch, multiple ETH transaction happened without my confirmation. Now, the company is asking me to give back their ethereum. Duplication happened while sending ETH to another person, is it possible to get that person's personal information using ETH address? or with any legal ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not easily doable to attach a person to an Ethereum address unless they've either volunteered to make that association or they've been careless in some way (for example, posting their address to an online forum such as this). If you are using an online account such as CoinBase, then they can connect you, of course, since they have all your banking info, etc.

If you know the account address of the `sending` account then you should be able to get the `recipient`, but you won't be able to attach it without the above being true.